# How to list results using state when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, jsx

I am trying to write a component that lists a set of results when clicking the Find button. However when I click the Find button, the `results` state variable is not being reset when I call `setResults([])`.

Also it does not return each result in the results array, only the latest one. Could I be calling `results.map` or `result.resultItems.map` incorrectly as well?

This is what I look like when I click the Find button three times:

[image: State not being reset, and only returns latest result]

I need it to look like this, even when clicking the Find button again:

[image: Correct outcome]

```
  const SearchContact = () => {
    const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

    const handleFind = () => {
      setResults([]);

      const response = [
        { name: "Tim", email: "timothy@outlook.com" },
        { name: "Fred", email: "fred@outlook.com" }
      ];

      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
        const resultItems = [];

        resultItems.push(<div>{response[i].name}</div>);
        resultItems.push(<div>{response[i].email}</div>);

        setResults([...results, { resultItems: resultItems }]);
      }
    }

    return (
      <Button onClick={handleFind}>Find</Button>
        {results.map((result, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              {result.resultItems.map((resultItem, index) => {
                return <div key={index}>{resultItem}</div>;
              })}
            </div>
          );
      })}
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try tihs:

```
 const SearchContact = () => {
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  const handleFind = () => {
    const response = [
      { name: "Tim", email: "timothy@outlook.com" },
      { name: "Fred", email: "fred@outlook.com" }
    ];

    const newResults = response.map((item) => {
      const resultItems = [
        <div key="name">{item.name}</div>,
        <div key="email">{item.email}</div>
      ];

      return { resultItems };
    });

    setResults(newResults);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleFind}>Find</Button>
      {results.map((result, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          {result.resultItems.map((resultItem, idx) => (
            <div key={idx}>{resultItem}</div>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can improve your answer (making it more likely to be accepted & upvoted) by adding an explanation of what the code does/what changes you made to it.

Comment: This works great, I forgot that you could use map to transform elements

Answer (score 0):

Simply call `setResults(results)` in the handleFind function, no need to call `setResults([])`, or any of the looping logic, like this:

```js
    const handleFind = () => {

      // probably change to an API call in future
      const response = [
        { name: "Tim", email: "timothy@outlook.com" },
        { name: "Fred", email: "fred@outlook.com" }
      ];
      setResults(response);
      }
    }
```

and the in the JSX do:

```js
 {results.map((result, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <div>{result.name}</div>
              <div>{result.email}</div>
            </div>
          );
      })}
```

Comment: This is a great refactor for my example, however for my next step I do still need the result.resultItems array as I want to push to the resultItems based on conditions. For example:

`const responseResults = response.map((responseItem) => {`
`const resultItems = [];`
`if (!responseItem.individual) {`
`resultItems.push(<div>{responseItem.companyName}</div>);`
`}`


If you have a suggestion on a cleaner way to do this then let me know